# How to get a single recall score for all images using Torchmetrics module

Tags: python, computer-vision, precision-recall, torchmetrics

Is there a way to get a single recall score for all the images? Because when I use `MeanAveragePrecision` class with `extended_summary=True` it gives multiple values, similar to the following:

`'recall': tensor([[[[0.2922, 0.8148, 0.8148], [0.1226, 0.6415, 0.6415], [0.3920, 0.9440, 0.9440], [0.7500, 1.0000, 1.0000]]]], dtype=torch.float64)}`